# Is possible install Eclipse IDE in Honeycomb?

Tags: applications, tablet, 3.0-honeycomb

Since Eclipse IDE can run in Linux and the new Honeycomb has a Linux Kernel, can Eclipse IDE run in Android Honeycomb ?

I know that isn't pretty much comfortable coding in a tablet, but I'd want to use for UML modeling.

Comment: FYI - all Android versions have a Linux-based kernel, not just Honeycomb.

Comment: You need much more than a compatible kernel to run most apps. Though it is at least a good base to start from. Best you can hope is that someone is able to use something like the Native Dev Kit to port a version of Eclipse IDE, though I believe much of Eclipse is Java based, so it my be possible to port via Dalvik, though that won't be a small job either.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### No.

As you might know, Eclipse has various problems running in different flavors of Linux (which is why Ubuntu has an official repository version of it, and all that).  Android is even worse -- while based on Linux, it's a completely different operating system.  A similar question would be, "Is is possible to install a *nix version of Eclipse in Mac OS?"

Answer (score 11):

To expand a bit on the previous 'No' answers, it's not just the kernel, but the rest of the OS which makes a big difference. Applications developed for linux expect a certain set of libraries (shared bits of code) to exist and do what the application expects. They also sometimes expect a certain filesystem structure and other dependencies.

Not all linux distributions include the same libraries, filesystem layout, or have other differences. That's why you'll often see linux applications distributed as a .tar.gz file with a script to compile it yourself; that makes it a bit more cross-platform.

Some executables, like command-line utilities, can be cross-compiled to work on android because they don't have as many complex requirements as a big complex application like Eclipse. Android's different enough that there aren't (yet) straightforward ways to compile standard linux GUI applications to work on it.

Answer (score 10):

No is the short answer.

The android OS is built on the Linux kernel. There are a lot of differences between the Android OS and the average Linux distro, and some of these differences are critical to installing Eclipse.

Comment: Most notably -- proper JRE/JDK. Android's Dalvik is quite different from all "blessed" Java implementations, both in architecture and bytecode.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding a little bit on [Ben Griffths answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/is-possible-install-eclipse-ide-in-honeycomb/6270#6270) and Martin Tapankov's comment, no, you can't run Eclipse on Android because there isn't a Java Runtime Environment to run Eclipse and there isn't a build of the Java Development Kit for Android. Although most Android apps are written in Java, Android doesn't have a JRE; Android uses Dalvik which is a completely different runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Best bet, look into running chrooted linux off of your honeycomb tablet (i know it can be done on the motorola xoom - http://www.offensive-security.com/backtrack/backtrack-5-on-a-motorola-xoom/).

Basically its just an arm build of that linux distro running on your xoom. Once in that environment install whatever traditional linux stuff you want. The arm version of backtrack is on the website, its a info security linux distro so theres lots of tools i use at work. Anyway, happy hunting, i know eclipse can be setup in backtrack so less work for you to go, it might even be in the apt-get repo for it as well.

Comment: side note you have to be rooted to do that. and here is a link to the install steps: http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1414534.htm

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to install eclipse on android is to [install a virtual ubuntu](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/) on your android device

Answer (score 1):

That is a very interesting question! Since sooner or later we'll be running android on our desktops.

If you want Eclipse run on android, you'll need to compile all its dependencies. Linux kernel is not a problem. And even porting Eclipse's Java codebase to run in Dalvik is not a problem. The problem is eclipse's UI.

Eclipse UI is build with SWT - an amazing toolkit that enables native look of a Java program on many plaforms. To start with, you'll have to port SWT on android. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/246310/736679/#msg_736679
AFAIK, there's currently no plans to port SWT on Android.

So, the only easy solution to this is running both linux distro and android at the same time. This can be done with "any linux distro built for arm"+chroot+vnc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Install a regular linux distro on your Android along side whichever AndroidOS you have and run whatever Linux apps you want:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dyndns.sven_ola.debian_kit