# Can I run a Linux executable on Android?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, command-line

I wondered if it is possible to run a Linux executable on Android so I made a simple console application in Code::Blocks in C++ (I am using Ubuntu Linux), built it in release mode and copied it into a virtual device in GenyMotion (because I don't have a real x86 Android device).

I installed the app called material terminal on the virtual device and moved the executable into /data/local/tmp.

I gave it execute permissions by typing: chmod 777 hwrel.

Then I tried to run it by typing ./hwrel ,but it said sh: ./hwrel: no such file or directory.

Is it even possible to run Linux executables on Android?

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Can you run Linux command line apps on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12207/44325)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but due to Android using a different libc and architecture you'll need to compile your program with android-ndk.

Comment: But the architecture is the same since I am using a GenyMotion for this purpose.